# Use If flexibly to get average

Tags: excel, if-statement, average

I want to calculate the response time across multiple subjects with one restriction: only response time from the correct trials should be included in the average. The structure of my data looks like below (for simplicity, I show only 3 subjects and 10 trials, in reality, I have many more)

[image: Table]

I would like to get average of RT across subj1, subj2, and subj2 for each of the  trials. Only correct trials are included in the average. 0 and 1 are used to denote incorrect and correct trials, respectively. For instance, for cell G2, I would only include B2 and D2 in the average, F2 is left out since the ACC for that trial from that subject is 0. I imagined using If AND function to include the appropriate RT but with many subjects, this becomes very clumsy. Does anyone have a clever solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `0 * anything = 0`, `G2 = SUM(A2*B2,C2*D2,E2*F2)/SUM(A2,C2,E2)`

Comment: Great and simple solution! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `AVERAGE` and an array formula which can be easily extended to larger ranges, i.e.

`=AVERAGE(IF((RIGHT(B$1:F$1,2)="RT")*(A2:E2=1),B2:F2)`

confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

...or even simpler with `AVERAGEIFS` like this

`=AVERAGEIFS(B2:F2,A2:E2,1,B$1:F$1,"*RT")`

note the “offset” ranges

Comment: This is definitely more scalable!

Comment: You can even use =AVERAGEIF(A2:E2,1,B2:F2) but that would get wrong results if any of the RT columns can have value 1

Comment: No 1's are to be expected in those RT columns. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Actually I suppose you can use AVERAGEIFS to get the same as my first suggestion....but without CSE and a bit shorter, see edit above